# Searching for duplicate values in rows of pandas dataframes Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, format

I want to add a piece of function down to the pandas dataframe below where it shows rows that have the `open,high,low,close` values to be the exact same. The very last row in the dataframe is True for this case. I want to also write a piece of code that shows the number of columns that have the same exact column value, if you look at the 3rd and fourth row the `low` column has the values `37350` repeated twice consecutively. So I want to make a function that states the maximum number of consecutive duplicates and the indexes of the rows of where it starts and ends.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime

A =[[1645661520000, 37352.0, 37376.5, 37352.0, 37376.0, 15.56119087], 
[1645661580000, 37376.0, 37414.0, 37376.0, 37414.0, 49.38248589], 
[1645661640000, 37414.0, 37414.0, 37350.0, 37350.0, 45.70306699], 
[1645661700000, 37350.0, 37374.0, 37350.0, 37373.5, 14.4306948], 
[1645661760000, 37373.5, 37388.0, 37373.5, 37388.0, 3.59340947], 
[1645661820000, 37388.0, 37388.0, 37388.0, 37388.0, 21.45525727]]

column_names = ["Unix","Open", "High","Low", "Close", "Volume"]
df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=column_names)
#Dates = Local_timezone(df["Unix"].to_numpy()/1000)
df.insert(1,"Date", pd.to_datetime(df["Unix"].to_numpy()/1000,unit='s'))
```

Expected output

```
Rows with all duplicate values: 6 # 1645661820000, 37388.0, 37388.0, 37388.0, 37388.0, 21.45525727
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `nunique`

```
cond = df[["Open", "High","Low", "Close"]].apply(pd.Series.nunique,1).eq(1)
Out[344]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
#row = df['cond']
```